# iOS - Load cells one by one

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I want to load the cell of a collection view one by one using the API `collectionView.insertItems(at:)`. There are many answers online which accomplish this by animating the `alpha` of the cell inside of `willDisplayCell` and other methods, for example here - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33410482/table-view-cell-load-animation-one-after-another). However, nothing works perfectly. The reason for using `collectionView.insertItems(at:)` is that the animation is already built in and no hacks needed.

However using `collectionView.insertItems(at:)`, I get error such as:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception  'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of items in section 0.  The number of items contained in an
>   existing section after the update (5) must be equal to the number of
>   items contained in that section before the update (5), plus or minus
>   the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted,
>   0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of items moved into or out of
>   that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

This is an example of what I have, it's crashing as shown above, but it's a start I think in the right direction (hopefully):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    /// This array is populated from a network call.
    let images = [Image]()

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        animateCells()
    }

    func animateCells() {
        let indexPaths = [IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0),
                          IndexPath(item: 1, section: 0),
                          IndexPath(item: 2, section: 0),
                          IndexPath(item: 3, section: 0),
                          IndexPath(item: 4, section: 0)]

        for indexPath in indexPaths {
            let delayTime = 0.1 + Double(indexPath.row) * 0.3

            delay(delayTime) {
                self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
                    self.collectionView.insertItems(at: [indexPath])
                }, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }

    func delay(_ delay: TimeInterval, closure: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let when = DispatchTime.now() + delay
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: closure)
    }
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return images.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        return cell
    }
}
```

One of the main problems I see is that I do `return images.count` inside of `numberOfItemsInSection`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Would you please select any answer as a right one so that could help other visitors to find their mistake.

Comment: @GovindPrajapati Haven't tried answers out yet, will soon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made one demo with your code and found your mistake

> When you are inserting items in your collection view there are already 5 items in your collection view in that position so you can not insert new cells there because your images array has only 5 items which are already been displayed.

Please find below working code ->

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    //Array for collectionView
    var images :[UIImage] = []

    //This array will populate from network call
    var arrAllImagesFromNetwork : [UIImage] = Array(repeating: UIImage(named: "img1")!, count: 5)

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        animateCells()

    }

    func animateCells() {
        let indexPaths = [IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0),
                          IndexPath(item: 1, section: 0),
                          IndexPath(item: 2, section: 0),
                          IndexPath(item: 3, section: 0),
                          IndexPath(item: 4, section: 0)]



        for indexPath in indexPaths {
            let delayTime = 0.1 + Double(indexPath.row) * 0.3

            delay(delayTime) {

                self.images.append(self.arrAllImagesFromNetwork[indexPath.row])

                self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
                    self.collectionView.insertItems(at: [indexPath])
                }, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }

    func delay(_ delay: TimeInterval, closure: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let when = DispatchTime.now() + delay
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: closure)
    }
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return images.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing `self.images.append(indexPath.row)`? The array `images` is for an actual object, I changed my code to make this more noticeable by doing `let images = [Image]()`. Sorry if it wasn't clear. Does this answer still work?

Comment: For that better, you take two arrays one to store all images received from network call and one to populate collection view. Please have a look at the edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to append element to `images`with delay too?

```
var images = Array(repeating: 0, count: 0)

delay(delayTime) {
     self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
                self.images.append(0)       
                self.collectionView.insertItems(at: [indexPath])
     }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Would it be better to have 2 different arrays working together somehow? Instead of `append`'ing to the actual array, not sure

Comment: Could you please refactor your code to use actual objects? I updated my question to be more clear, so instead of `var images = Array(repeating: 0, count: 10)`, I now have `let images = [Image]()`. The array of `Image`'s comes from a network call.